# Upgrade jdk version of Tomcat docker container to 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, docker

i've a web application on windows running from eclipse, with xampp for apache and mysql. It use jdk v `1.8`.

Now, i want to deploy in inside a docker tomcat container. I've created a container from tomcat official image... but i've saw that its jdk version is `1.7` ... so there are some error when i try to run web-app under container (from tomcat logs i see `unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class)`

So.. how can i solve my problem?

Comment: There are official images with JRE 8. https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/ lists `-jre8` versions for 8.0 and 8.5. Which one are you using?

Comment: i was creating a docker container selecting only "tomcat" official image (i.e. docker run -p PORT:PORT --name mytomcat tomcat). Now i'm using tomcat:8.0, but i've this problem using this container: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270692/connect-a-web-app-on-tomcat-container-to-mysql-container-via-hibernate

Answer (score 3):

There are almost all versions of tomcat version [available](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/) with openjre 8. However if you want to use JDK for some reason OR you are using some version of tomcat which does not have jre 8 runtime OR you want to use oracle JDK then following are 2 ways to have jdk 8

1. You create your own docker file and extend the tomcat docker image.
2. You use docker commit functionality. Instead of running docker like `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0` run it as `docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 tomcat:8.0 bash`. This will display the bash shell. You can then install jdk8 using this [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-in-debian.html). Do [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) and you would be able to use that image anywhere.

Option 1 is always preferable as you have greater control over the image.

Comment: Thanks, now i'm using tomcat:8.0, but i've this problem using this container: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270692/connect-a-web-app-on-tomcat-container-to-mysql-container-via-hibernate

Comment: could you accept this answer for the question asked ? I will comment on the other question

Comment: @GauravJ for some libraries such as Jasper, openjdk is not an option and using jdk is the only alternative. I also faced the same issue recently and having jdk on my Docker container was the only option for my application to behave as expected